# Using Linq extension on Array class

Tags: c#, arrays, select, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to build a `SelectList` from an `Enum`.

Why are the `Linq` extension methods not available on `Array`?

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
var test = values.Select(x => x); // compile error
```

But I can write it this way and it compiles...

```
var test = from Enum e in values select new { e };
```

I don't normally use this style of syntax so I'm not really familiar with it, but isn't the above essentially the same as the lambda query which doesn't compile?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method to get an `IEnumerable<T>` that can be queried using LINQ:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
var test = values.OfType<int>().Select(x => x);
```